# Login loop on Ubuntu 20.4 with x11 after update

Tags: grub2, kernel, xorg, login

I am using Ubuntu 20.4lts(single os without dual boot). After an update yesterday, I cannot log in any more with x11 on my desktop. The only way to login is using wayland, which creates problems for me as it doesn't work for a number of application that I regularly use eg. screen-sharing on discord, vim-zathura synctex, xdotool and many others.

I tried all the usual things mentioned here, change kernels, modify grub, reinstall and auto login on gdm3, uninstall chrome remote desktop however it doesn't work still.

Any information regarding solving the issue or location of logs would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Output of auth.log

```
Nov  2 14:18:17 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov  2 14:18:30 Guest2-Esprimo sudo:   mmcrjx : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/mmcrjx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less /var/log/auth.log
Nov  2 14:18:30 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:18:48 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:22 (system bus name :1.764, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user mmcrjx
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: Session 22 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: Removed session 22.
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: New session c5 of user gdm.
Nov  2 14:18:57 Guest2-Esprimo systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:18:59 Guest2-Esprimo polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c5 (system bus name :1.868 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user mmcrjx by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: New session 25 of user mmcrjx.
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user mmcrjx
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: Session 25 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov  2 14:19:06 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: Removed session 25.
Nov  2 14:19:13 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Nov  2 14:19:13 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Nov  2 14:19:13 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user mmcrjx by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:19:13 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: New session 26 of user mmcrjx.
Nov  2 14:19:13 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-password]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Nov  2 14:19:14 Guest2-Esprimo gnome-keyring-daemon[50381]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Nov  2 14:19:14 Guest2-Esprimo gnome-keyring-daemon[50381]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
Nov  2 14:19:14 Guest2-Esprimo gnome-keyring-daemon[50381]: The SSH agent was already initialized
Nov  2 14:19:15 Guest2-Esprimo polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:26 (system bus name :1.896 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Nov  2 14:19:17 Guest2-Esprimo gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Nov  2 14:19:17 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: Session c5 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov  2 14:19:17 Guest2-Esprimo systemd-logind[1080]: Removed session c5.
Nov  2 14:19:17 Guest2-Esprimo polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c5 (system bus name :1.868, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Nov  2 14:19:18 Guest2-Esprimo PackageKit: uid 1001 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Nov  2 14:19:18 Guest2-Esprimo PackageKit: uid 1001 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Nov  2 14:19:23 Guest2-Esprimo dbus-daemon[1040]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Nov  2 14:19:30 Guest2-Esprimo sudo:   mmcrjx : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/mmcrjx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less /var/log/auth.log
Nov  2 14:19:30 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:19:58 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov  2 14:20:03 Guest2-Esprimo sudo:   mmcrjx : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/mmcrjx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/snap/bin/nvim /var/log/auth.log
Nov  2 14:20:03 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:20:18 Guest2-Esprimo pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Nov  2 14:20:18 Guest2-Esprimo pkexec[52984]: mmcrjx: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/mmcrjx] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Nov  2 14:20:19 Guest2-Esprimo PackageKit: uid 1001 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Nov  2 14:20:19 Guest2-Esprimo PackageKit: uid 1001 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Nov  2 14:22:14 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov  2 14:22:42 Guest2-Esprimo sudo:   mmcrjx : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/mmcrjx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/snap/bin/nvim /var/log/auth.log
Nov  2 14:22:42 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov  2 14:23:17 Guest2-Esprimo pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Nov  2 14:23:17 Guest2-Esprimo pkexec[54942]: mmcrjx: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/mmcrjx] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Nov  2 14:24:55 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov  2 14:25:31 Guest2-Esprimo sudo:   mmcrjx : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/mmcrjx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit /var/log/auth.log
Nov  2 14:25:31 Guest2-Esprimo sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Did you get a kernel update in that last update?

Comment: Most probably, however, I am not sure how to check that.